# How to get a select list in html to align right in html, the whole dropdown list when clicked?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a select list and a button underneath it, however when the list is selects the options cover the button which is what I am trying to avoid. Been at it for hour, and its frustrating how some so simple is kicking my butt. Below is my code and a picture of what it should look like. Any help would be appreciated, not too savvy with html but I looked high and above for a solution with no luck.

```
   <div class="col">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" style="float:right">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <button v-on:click="getRandomFact" type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-info">Get Fact </button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

[Example of what the select list should look like when clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILtCK.png)

Comment: Do you mean that when you open the dropdown menu it covers the "get a fact" button?

Comment: @gerik Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly (i.e. that when you "select"/open the dropdown menu it covers the button), you can't "right align" these elements because it's most likely that the drop down and the button know nothing about one another - i.e. they are not "in flow" with one another.

Dropdown menus are typically implemented such that the "button" triggers an action to cause the menu content to be displayed immediately below whatever has triggered it and above any other content on the page (as long as the z-index is lower).

In other words you need to look into changing the content of the dropdown lists own absolute/relative position totally on it's own - but taking into account the size of the button you don't want it to cover.

**EDIT**

Looking at this more closely I see it doesn't look like this is readily available via a "normal" select dropdown as the code is.  The standard display is to cover the entire span of the option box.  This means that in order to get this to work you would have to implement it with a customized dropdown display.

I realize this is probably way overkill for what you're looking for, but I found this answer on codepen by Yusuf which you could look over if you're dying for this feature:

https://codepen.io/yy/pen/vOYqYV?editors=1000

You'll notice the additional margin-left below the given margin settings in the .custom-options.

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
    <select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="Source Type">
        <option value="profile">Profile</option>
        <option value="word">Word</option>
        <option value="hashtag">Hashtag</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: #ededed;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/** Custom Select **/
.custom-select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}
.custom-select-wrapper select {
  display: none;
}
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.custom-select-trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 0 84px 0 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: #5c9cd8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  .custom-select-trigger:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 10px; height: 10px;
    top: 50%; right: 25px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
  }
  .custom-select.opened .custom-select-trigger:after {
    margin-top: 3px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-50%);
  }
.custom-options {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  margin-left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.07);
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}
.custom-select.opened .custom-options {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.custom-options:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  bottom: 100%; right: 25px;
  width: 7px; height: 7px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  border-top: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  border-left: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.option-hover:before {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
.custom-option {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #b5b5b5;
  line-height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.custom-option:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.custom-option:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
.custom-option:hover,
.custom-option.selection {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".custom-select").each(function() {
  var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
  id      = $(this).attr("id"),
  name    = $(this).attr("name");
var template =  '<div class="' + classes + '">';
  template += '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' + 
  $(this).attr("placeholder") + '</span>';
  template += '<div class="custom-options">';
  $(this).find("option").each(function() {
    template += '<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
  });
  template += '</div></div>';

  $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).after(template);
});
$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});
$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
  $('html').one('click',function() {
  $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
});
$(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select").val($(this).data("value"));
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").find(".custom-option").removeClass("selection");
  $(this).addClass("selection");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").find(".custom-select-trigger").text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: when adding the `margin-left:3rem` or `left:3rem` styles to the selection tags the whole thing gets shifted not just the dropdown when clicked. I tried to do `option{ left: 30px; }` and '`margin-left` in styles tags but nothing happens.

Comment: Apologies as I guess I did say the dropdown list: remember what you're trying to do is to change the display of the drop down content.  Open the dropdown and inspect it with your dev-tools.  You should be able to isolate the dropdown content element (i.e. the div or list or form or whatever it is that's 'hopefully' wrapping the options) and change it's location.

Comment: np, I did try to isolate the style of what was styling the content of the dropdown content in my browsers developer tools, but was unsuccessful.